# Connecting 2 database table using eloquent in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

so i'm trying to connect an attribute of userid from a table let's say carts, with the id in the table let's say users so i can retrieve the attribute name and then show them in the webpage, but i'm little confused on how to connect them, can anyone help me?, thank you

Controller

```php
public function details($id){
    $order = Cart::where('id',$id)->first();

    //here's where i want to connect the id
    $user = Cart::where('userid')->first();

    return view('admin.order.details', compact('order', 'user'));
}
```

model

```php
class Cart extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'userid','alamatid','code','type','quantity','kurir','total','img_picture','note',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'remember_token',
];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want a relationship,

in your cart model you can add a function saying the owning/belongning of the model

for example if the cart belongs to a user you can add to your cart model

```
function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Notice that `App\User` is the route to your user model, and in your cart table you must have an `user_id` column.

then your query should be something like this

```
$order = Cart::with('user')->find($id);
```

to access the name in the user table in your view you could do this

```
{{ $order->user->name }}
```

Comment: sorry, i did miss the argument of the function, you have to pass the id of the cart

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect between users and carts with the adequate relationship.

Say if a user has a single cart and a cart belongs to some user, then we need to have a one-to-one relationship https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one